# Regular expression for e-mail domain (not basic e-mail verification)

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently using

```
if(preg_match('~@(semo\.edu|uni\.uu\.se|)$~', $email))
```

as a domain check.

However I need to only check if the e-mail ends with the domains above. So for instance, all these need to be accepted:

```
hello@semo.edu
hello@student.semo.edu
hello@cool.teachers.semo.edu
```

So I'm guessing I need something after the @ but before the ( which is something like "any random string or empty string". Any regexp-ninjas out there who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`([^@]*\.)?` works if you already know you're dealing with a [valid email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378). Explanation: it's either empty, or anything that ends with a period but does not contain an ampersand. So `student.cs.semo.edu` matches, as does plain `semo.edu`, but not `me@notreallysemo.edu`. So:

```
~@([^@]*\.)?(semo\.edu|uni\.uu\.se)$~
```

Note that I've removed the last `|` from your original regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*` to match none or more characters (letters, numbers or dot):

`~@[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*(semo\.edu|uni\.uu\.se|)$~`

Comment: That matches `me@notreallysemo.edu`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Good point. Your solution is much more elegant. +1

Answer (score 0):

Well `.*` will match anything. But you don't actually want that. There are a number of characters that are invalid in a domain name (ex. a space). Instead you want something more like this:

```
[\w.]*
```

I might not have all of the allowed characters, but that will get you [A-Za-z0-9_.]. The idea is that you make a list of all the allowed characters in the square brakets and then use `*` to say none or more of them.

Comment: That too matches `me@notreallysemo.edu`.